# Postgresql: Get content of cursors returned by function

Tags: postgresql, cursors, multiple-cursor

A psql-function (sp_some_function) returns 2 cursors:

```
create or replace function sp_some_function() RETURNS SETOF REFCURSOR
as 
$BODY$

  declare 

    c_one   refcursor                   := 'one'         ;
    c_two   refcursor                   := 'two'         ;

  begin

      open c_one   for
        select *
          from TABLE_1;

     return next c_one   ;

     open c_two   for
        select *
          from TABLE_2;

     return next c_two   ;

  return;
end
$BODY$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
```

I want to see what data each of the 2 cursors "contains".

To this end I wrote the following script:

```
DO $$                    

BEGIN                    

 select sp_some_function(); 


 FETCH ALL IN "one";
 FETCH ALL IN "two";


END;                     
$$;
```

Running the script results in the following error message:

```
ERROR:  "one" is not a known variable
```

I also tried the following:

```
DO $$                    

BEGIN                    

 select sp_some_function(); 


 FETCH ALL IN c_one;
 FETCH ALL IN c_two;


END;                     
$$;
```

This resulted in the following error message:

```
ERROR:  c_one is not a known variable
```

Finally, I tried the following:

```
create or replace function sp_some_function() RETURNS SETOF REFCURSOR
as 
$BODY$

  declare 

    c_one   refcursor                   := 'one'         ;
    c_two   refcursor                   := 'two'         ;

  begin

      open c_one   for
        select *
          from TABLE_1;

     FETCH ALL IN c_one;

     return next c_one   ;

     open c_two   for
        select *
          from TABLE_2;



     FETCH ALL IN c_two;  

     return next c_two   ;

  return;
end
$BODY$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
```

This didn't work either.

... How can I get the content of the two cursors?

Comment: did you manage to find a answare to this?

Answer (score 1):

Your PL/pgSQL code is wrong.

You cannot use `SELECT` without `INTO` in PL/pgSQL.

The best thing for you is to do something like this (untested):

```
DECLARE
   c refcursor;
   a_row record;
BEGIN
   FOR c IN
      SELECT sp_some_function()
   LOOP
      LOOP
         FETCH c INTO a_row;
         EXIT IF NOT FOUND;
         /* do something with the result row */
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... unfortunately, these are unbound cursors so I'm getting the following error message: "cursor FOR loop must use a bound cursor variable"

Comment: Right, the cursor is already opened. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the below method to get the output

execute the below function

```
BEGIN;        -- begin Transaction             

 select sp_some_function();
```

here you will get the refcusor value copy that and then fetch the data from it.. for eg:

```
 FETCH ALL IN "refcursor_value1";  -- Execute it seperately to see the result
 FETCH ALL IN "refcursor_value2";  -- Execute it seperately to see the result


END;  -- end Transaction
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work ... I'm not getting the refcursor value.

Comment: The question is about PL/pgSQL.